# ldd can't find library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: unix, shared-libraries, ldd

I'm trying to get a system up and running, and am having problems with the OpenMotif shared libraries.  I have their directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it still can't find them.

Here's an example:

```
[root@intrepid netcool]# ldd /opt/netcool/omnibus/platform/linux2x86/bin/nco_* |grep 'not found'
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXpm.so.4 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXpm.so.4 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
[root@intrepid netcool]# find /usr/ -name libXm.so.3 
/usr/lib64/libXm.so.3
[root@intrepid netcool]# find /usr/ -name libXpm.so.4
/usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4
[root@intrepid netcool]# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/netcool/omnibus//platform/linux2x86/lib/:/opt/netcool//platform/linux2x86/lib/:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib64/
```

I'm probably doing something stupid, but I can't think of anything else to try.

EDIT: To answer a couple of the questions asked below:

```
[root@intrepid netcool]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
[root@intrepid netcool]# ldd /opt/netcool/omnibus/platform/linux2x86/bin/nco_* |grep 'not found'
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXpm.so.4 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXpm.so.4 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
[root@intrepid netcool]# ldconfig
[root@intrepid netcool]# ldd /opt/netcool/omnibus/platform/linux2x86/bin/nco_* |grep 'not found'
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXpm.so.4 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXpm.so.4 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXm.so.3 => not found
```

Ok, just tried to run one of the executables:

```
# ./bin/nco_xigen 
/opt/netcool//omnibus/platform/linux2x86/bin/nco_xigen: error while loading shared libraries: libXm.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Is this a 32 bit/64 bit thing?

Comment: Did you `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Yes, LD_LIBRARY_PATH was set and exported in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Did you re-source .bash_profile in your environment? Sorry to start so basic, but it's usually the basic stuff that trips up advanced programmers... #EDIT it would seem you did, since echo prints out the right directories. Hmm...

Comment: In the spirit of grasping at straws, could you run [ldconfig](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ldd-reports-shared-library-missing-but-library-exists-on-disk-725472/)?

Comment: Try `ldconfig -p | grep 'X[p]m'` that will search the `ld.so` cache.

Comment: Returned `libXpm.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4`.  Still the same output from ldd.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The binaries I had were looking for the 32-bit versions of the shared libraries, I had the 64-bit installed.  Stupid mistake.  LDD didn't produce a very insightful error message, but the binary did when I tried to run it.

Comment: We had exactly the same thing happen.  Originally our binary's error was obfuscated because it was launched by a vendor script. After several days we tried running it by hand and immediately saw the error.

Answer (score 17):

Did you export LD_LIBRARY_PATH? the `export` keyword tells Bash to send any variables to subprocesses - otherwise ldd will never see LD_LIBRARY_PATH.