# ldd can't find library

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, shared-libraries

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341044/ldd-cant-find-library-in-ld-library-path), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314983/ldd-says-not-found-even-though-library-is-in-my-ld-library-path) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279397/ldd-dont-find-path-how-to-add).

I've installed OpenCV in a costum path `/home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/install_icpc/lib`, where there is  `libopencv_core.so`:

```
luca@jarvis:~$ ldd /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/install_icpc/lib/libopencv_core.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffccb389000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f46af719000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f46af410000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f46af1f2000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f46aefea000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f46aedd0000)
    libimf.so => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libimf.so (0x00007f46ae8e3000)
    libsvml.so => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libsvml.so (0x00007f46ad9d8000)
    libirng.so => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libirng.so (0x00007f46ad663000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f46ad2e0000)
    libiomp5.so => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so (0x00007f46acf3d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f46acd27000)
    libintlc.so.5 => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libintlc.so.5 (0x00007f46acabc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f46ac6f3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055f67574e000)
```

I added the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and I executed `ldconfig`, but:

```
luca@jarvis:~$ ldd libopencv_core.so
ldd: ./libopencv_core.so: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

From `man ldd`:-

```
NAME

       ldd - print shared object dependencies
SYNOPSIS         top

       ldd [option]... file...
DESCRIPTION

       ldd prints the shared objects (shared libraries) required by each
       program or shared object specified on the command line.  An example
       of its use and output is the following:

       $ ldd /bin/ls
               linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc3563000)
               libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f87e5459000)
               libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f87e5254000)
               libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f87e4e92000)
               libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f87e4c22000)
               libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f87e4a1e000)
               /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005574bf12e000)
               libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f87e4817000)
               libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f87e45fa000)
```

The output of your command:

```
luca@jarvis:~$ ldd libopencv_core.so
ldd: ./libopencv_core.so: No such file or directory
```

says that the *program or shared object* supposedly *specified on the
commandline* does not exist in the implied directory = `./` = `/home/luca`.
We know it exists in `/home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/install_icpc/lib`.

If you run `ldd` *file*, where *file*, after shell expansion, is the pathname
of an existing file, then `ldd` will display the dynamic dependencies
of that file, as discovered by the dynamic linker with its usual reliance upon
the current `ldconfig` configuration and its usual regard to the operative
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment setting. It will not search your system
for files that might be alternate candidates for a *file* that does not exist
and display the dynamic dependencies of those candidates.